# .Net desktop application output files -- single EXE possible?

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

once upon a time I was an avid .NET desktop developer and am catching back up.  In the old days one thing I liked about it was that the output file was a single EXE -- super easy to move to and run on another machine (mostly for ad-hoc lab/engineering tools, not a deliverable product).  With the new frameworks (using .NET 6.0) it seems it outputs three necessary files for a simple forms project: an EXE, a DLL, and a .deps.json file.

I'm trying to find a simple explanation as to why this is, and also if there is a way to run the newer frameworks the old way: everything in a single EXE?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you publishing your app as 'self contained' and looking at the publish results?

Comment: Jonathan, it's a forms app so I just Build->Build Solution and it produces a target.  nothing about "publishing" so I wonder if you're referring to a web type project?  If not, where is the option for "self contained"?  thanks!